# Interface getting null

Tags: android, interface

In my application i am using a interface to get values from list.My list shows properly but when i click a list value the app gets crashes.Please help me out whats the problem.

Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] array;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private DropDownList dropDownList;
    private Button button;
    private DropDownAdapter adapter;
    private GetDropDownData getDropDownData;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Religion);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_show);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showDialog() {


        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dropdown_list);
        ListView lvDropDown = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv_drop_down);
        adapter = new DropDownAdapter(this, array);
        lvDropDown.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvDropDown.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                getDropDownData.getValue(array[position]);
                getDropDownData.getPosition(position);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();


    }


}
```

I think my interface is not initialized thats why my app is crashing

Getting Error at this line

```
 getDropDownData.getValue(array[position]);
```

Comment: where have you initialized getDropDownData ?

Comment: Whats is `getDropDownData` here.

Comment: As they say, you have to set getDropDownData to some object, right now it is null, so you get the error.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to set it?

Comment: @virendrao i dont know how to do it,please can you tell me/

Comment: I don't see why you'd want that interface there. You can access your data easily via the array. We might help you if you can tell us what it is that you want to do.

Comment: Ya i also tried using the array only but was getting error so tried to get the data what user selected via interface